# What's the advantage of using <router-link> over <a href="">?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org), the component `<router-link>` is provided for linking to routes. Example:

```
<router-link to="/foo">Link</router-link>
```

However, the following code seems to work the same:

```
<a href="#/foo">Link</a>
```

What is the advantage of `<router-link>` over just using `<a>`?

Answer (score 6):

Per the [doc for `<router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link):

> `<router-link>` is preferred over hard-coded `<a href="...">` for the
>   following reasons:
>
> - It works the same way in both HTML5 history mode and hash mode, so if you ever decide to switch mode, or when the router falls back to
>     hash mode in IE9, nothing needs to be changed.
> - In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page.
> - When you are using the base option in HTML5 history mode, you don't need to include it in to prop's URLs.

And also:

> In addition, the link automatically gets an active CSS class when the target route is active.